# flutter) There's a problem using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I'm going to develop apps and webs using firebase.
However, if I add firebase and try to use it, an error is output.

Below is the addition and test of Android firebase in the new project.

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^1.6.0
  #  firebase_auth: ^3.1.1
```

I put the google-services.json in the Android-app folder.
android-build.gradle

```
      dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}
```

app-build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' //bottom
```

And main.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text("12345"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It's error

```
    Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_platform_interface-4.0.1/lib/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:88:9: Error: 'Cthrow' isn't a type.
        Cthrow coreNotInitialized();
        ^^^^^^
../../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_platform_interface-4.0.1/lib/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:88:16: Error: Expected ';' after this.
        Cthrow coreNotInitialized();
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_platform_interface-4.0.1/lib/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:88:35: Error: Expected an identifier, but got ')'.
Try inserting an identifier before ')'.
        Cthrow coreNotInitialized();
                                  ^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/kevinyang/Desktop/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1005

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/kevinyang/Desktop/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 52s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I'm suffering from this problem for a long time. May I know the cause of this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this error is coming from `.pub-cache` so just flutter clean, if the error still persist delete all the .pub-cache then

flutter clean

and pub get

Comment: Hi, 
Thank you for your answers.

What's the location of the .pub-cache?

Comment: which os are u using?

Comment: Remove the package from dependencies in pubspec.yaml, run flutter packages get. And then add the package to dependencies again and running flutter packages get.This process has solved the problem for me in the past.

Comment: or flutter pub cache repair