# How can I fix this issue with flutter unity widget?

Tags: flutter, kotlin, compiler-errors

LOGS:

```
e: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_unity_widget-4.2.5\android\src\main\kotlin\com\xraph\plugin\flutter_unity_widget\FlutterUnityWidgetController.kt: (14, 27): Unresolved reference: MultiWindowSupport
e: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_unity_widget-4.2.5\android\src\main\kotlin\com\xraph\plugin\flutter_unity_widget\FlutterUnityWidgetController.kt: (232, 17): Unresolved reference: MultiWindowSupport
e: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_unity_widget-4.2.5\android\src\main\kotlin\com\xraph\plugin\flutter_unity_widget\FlutterUnityWidgetController.kt: (239, 17): Unresolved reference: MultiWindowSupport
e: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_unity_widget-4.2.5\android\src\main\kotlin\com\xraph\plugin\flutter_unity_widget\FlutterUnityWidgetController.kt: (245, 13): Unresolved reference: MultiWindowSupport
e: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_unity_widget-4.2.5\android\src\main\kotlin\com\xraph\plugin\flutter_unity_widget\FlutterUnityWidgetController.kt: (250, 13): Unresolved reference: MultiWindowSupport

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_unity_widget:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
```

I've added this :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Did : -flutter upgrade
-flutter clean
-flutter pub get
-flutter pub upgrade
-deleted android/.gradle

Answer (score 0):

This problem is from `.pub-cache` so just flutter clean, if the error still persist delete all the `.pub-cache` then

you can also check the link to related [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69794283/flutter-theres-a-problem-using-firebase/69794563#69794563)

flutter clean

and pub get